# Mask www.oldsite.com/home with www.newsite.com

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mask

How can I mask so all instances of www.oldsite.com are replaced with www.newsite.com

example:

I'd like to replace:
http://www.oldsite.com/home/b.jsp?id=9912&ln=115-991632

with www.newsite.com/home/b.jsp?id=9912&ln=115-991632

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Apache with the [Redirect directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.oldsite.com
    Redirect permanent /home/ http://www.newsite.com/home/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you only want to replace that page, you can create a .htaccess file with this content:

```
Redirect 301 /b.jsp?id=9912&ln=115-991632 http://www.newsite.com/home/b.jsp?id=9912&ln=115-991632
```

That's all I can think now. You should upload it to your /home directory.

Comment: Thank you, but what if I have 100 or so old links, is there a way to tell it to replace all "oldsite" with "newsite"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do at the application level, just print a location header:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Location: http://www.newsite.com'
```

To make it even better, you can place that cgi script at "home" (replace the directory with a script) and use the $PATH_INFO variable to do the correct thing

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Location: http://www.newsite.com/$PATH_INFO'
```